# как правильно делать сброс пароля?

Tags: html, python, cgi

Как правильно сбрасывать пароль? Делаю так:

- Генерирую случайный ключ, затем отсылаю ссылку вида: `мойсайт.ру/forgotpwd.cgi?email=мыло@мыло.ру&key=bfyuk478hjgg...`
- При переходе по ссылке считываю параметры — мыло и ключ — и, если нахожу их в базе, то вывожу форму для смены пароля.

На кнопку, по идее, нужно вешать новый обработчик, но как тогда этот обработчик узнает, что ключ не фейковый, и для какого мыла ему поменять пароль? Можно, конечно, сразу менять пароль пользователю на какой-нибудь, а потом уже, когда авторизуется, пусть меняет на какой надо, но всё же интересен первый вариант.

Comment: В обработчик формы смены пароля отправлять ключ из ссылки

Comment: скрытым полем? или явно?

Comment: Можно скрытым полем или сессией/куками.

Comment: спасибо. переписал часть кода, но заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так:

- пользователь заходит по ссылке смены пароля, вводит email (или какой-нибудь идентификатор), ему на почту отправляется письмо со ссылкой на смену пароля, вида `site.com/change-password?id=1c32cba3...`, при этом создается запись в отдельной таблице, где идентификатором является этот самый ID, и еще хранится email, куда прислать новый пароль и/или можно id юзера, время создания записи.
- пользователь переходит по ссылке при чтении письма, на сервере по ID ищется email/ID юзера, проверяется, не прошло ли более 24 часов со времени создания записи, если всё ок - заменяется пароль на сгенерированную 6-10 символьную строку, и, этот пароль присылается опять по тому же емейлу.

Всё. Не забудьте новый захешировать пароль, перед вставкой в базу.

Comment: ну то есть вы сами выставляете пользователю пароль.

Comment: Ну разговор идет о сбросе пароля, а не о смене.